# Python: pygame deleting image on mouse click and creating it again

Tags: python, image, pygame, mouse

im trying to make a simple game where the there are soldiers coming towards you and when you click them to "kill" them they go at the back of the screen and start to come towards you, so on.....
however i'm having trouble with pygame mouse click event and it just doesnt work.
heres my code so far:

```
import pygame, math
from random import randrange

import sys, math, pygame
from operator import itemgetter

def getKey(customobj):
    return customobj.getKey()

class Point3D:
    def __init__(self, imfiles, nfrm, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = float(x), float(y), float(z)
        self.frms = []
        self.nfrm=nfrm
        self.index=0
        for k in range(0,nfrm):
            im=pygame.image.load(imfiles+'_'+str(k+1)+'.png')
            im.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
            self.frms.append(im)       

    def

    project(self, win_width, win_height, fov, viewer_distance):
    """ Transforms this 3D point to 2D using a perspective projection. """
    factor = fov / (viewer_distance + self.z)
    x = self.x * factor + win_width / 2
    y = -self.y * factor + win_height / 2
    return Point3D(x, y, self.z)

def draw3D(self, wsurface, fov, viewer_distance, max_depth):
    win_width=wsurface.get_width()
    win_height=wsurface.get_height()
    factor = fov / (viewer_distance + self.z)
    x = self.x * factor + win_width / 2
    y = -self.y * factor + win_height / 2
    size = int((1 - float(self.z) / max_depth) * 64)
    im=pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.frms[self.index],(size,size))
    try:
        wsurface.blit(im, (x, y))
    except:
        print((x,y))
    self.index=self.index+1
    if self.index >= self.nfrm:
      self.index=0

def getKey(self):
    return -self.z


class StartField:
def __init__(self, num_stars, max_depth):
    pygame.init()

    myWin = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 450), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Drawing')

    self.screen = myWin.subsurface([0,0,640,400]);
    self.txtwin = myWin.subsurface([0,400,640,50]);
    pygame.display.set_caption("Task C")

    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.num_stars = num_stars
    self.max_depth = max_depth

    self.init_stars()

def init_stars(self):
    """ Create the starfield """
    self.stars = []
    for i in range(self.num_stars):
        # A star is represented as a list with this format: [X,Y,Z]
        star = Point3D('im',8,randrange(-25,25), randrange(-25,25), randrange(1, self.max_depth))
        self.stars.append(star)

def move_and_draw_stars(self):
    """ Move and draw the stars """
    origin_x = self.screen.get_width() / 2
    origin_y = self.screen.get_height() / 2

    stars=sorted(self.stars,key = getKey)

    for star in stars:
        # The Z component is decreased on each frame.
        star.z -= 0.05

        # If the star has past the screen (I mean Z<=0) then we
        # reposition it far away from the screen (Z=max_depth)
        # with random X and Y coordinates.
        if star.z <= 0:
            star.x = randrange(-25,25)
            star.y = randrange(-25,25)
            star.z = self.max_depth

        # Convert the 3D coordinates to 2D using perspective projection.
        star.draw3D(self.screen, 128, 0, self.max_depth)

def run(self):
    """ Main Loop """        
    bgPicture =    pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('Starfield.jpg'),(self.screen.get_width(),self.screen.get_height()))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)       

    while 1:
        # Lock the framerate at 50 FPS.
        self.clock.tick(50)

        # Handle events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return

        self.screen.blit(bgPicture, [0,0])
        self.move_and_draw_stars()

        # Text window outputs
        self.txtwin.fill([200,200,200])
        text = font.render("Total Score: ", 1, (10, 10, 10))
        self.txtwin.blit(text, [5, 5])

        pygame.display.update()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
  StartField(256, 24).run()


        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("MuseUprising.mp3")

        sounda.play()
```

Comment: What does, "it just doesnt work," mean? What _does_ happen? Do you get any error messages? What are they? What line of code do they reference?

Comment: the objects are meant to come towards the screen from far until they reach you, clicking them doesnt do anything i tried using using pygame.mouse.get_pos to get the position of the mouse, then adding the pygame.mouse.get_pressed() to see if its been pressed, ive used Sprite to check if the mouse was over the image clicked_sprites = [s for s in sprites if s.rect.collidepoint(pos)] then used Sprite.remove() to remove the image and adding it again using sprite.add()

Answer (score 0):

To test for the left mouse button:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
```

If give the soldier a pygame.Rect you can use that to check for collision with the mouse pointer like this:

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
```

Comment: how do i give the soldier a pygame.Rect? the other code you gave me seems similar to what i had in mind

Comment: Sorry for the delay, have been at work.  I am assuming you are using the point3D class for the soldiers?  Add a rect there, set to None:    self.rect = None.  In the draw function, set the actual rect co-ords using the x and y and image size: `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, im.get_width(), im.get_height())`